# How to delete a specific branch using gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

This is the script to delete a branch after merge to master branch

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo.clone_from(SSHURL, newversiontag)
merge = repo.git.merge('origin/'+ newversiontag)
repo.git.push('--set-upstream', 'origin', 'master')
tag = repo.create_tag(newversiontag)
repo.git.push('--set-upstream', 'origin',tag)
repo.delete_head(newversiontag)
```

Error: this is the I am getting.Please help me  how to delete a specific branch in git using script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Clone.py", line 78, in <module>
    repo.delete_head(newversiontag)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 394, in delete_head
    return Head.delete(self, *heads, **kwargs)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/refs/head.py", line 127, in delete
    repo.git.branch(flag, *heads)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 545, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1014, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 825, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git branch -d 2.0
  stderr: 'error: branch '2.0' not found.'
```

Comment: Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520049/737440), found in another similar question